# Custom canvas star creator. With code to produce drawing

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Simple star designer for HTML canvas. Allows you to change every variable about how to draw the star.

This can be used to create squares, triangle, circles, hexagons, etc. But isn't an efficient way to create them and is only recommended for creating star shapes.

Note! the rotation is purely for show and isn't included in the produced code snippet.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const cX = canvas.width / 2;
        const cY = canvas.height / 2;
        let radius = 25;
        let innerRadius = 10;
        let steps = 5;
        let eachStepRadian = (2 * Math.PI) / steps;
        let lineWidth = 5;
        let rotationSpeed = 0;
        let rotation = 0;
        let fillColor = 'blue';
        let strokeColor = 'black';

        document.getElementById('point-count').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            steps = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('rotation-speed').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            rotationSpeed = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('radius').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            radius = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('inner-radius').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            innerRadius = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('line-width').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            lineWidth = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('fill-color').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            fillColor = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('stroke-color').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = '';
            strokeColor = e.target.value;
        })

        document.getElementById('produce-code').addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementById('code-to-make').innerHTML = `
                const canvas = document.getElementById('#your-canvas-id#');
                <br>
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                <br>
                const cX = canvas.width / 2;
                <br>
                const cY = canvas.height / 2;
                <br>
                const eachStepRadian = (2 * Math.PI) / ${steps};
                <br><br>
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) // clear canvas before drawing new star
                <br>
                ctx.beginPath();
                <br><br>
                // batch drawings together for performance sake
                <br>
                for (let i = 0; i < ${steps + 1}; i += 1) {
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsplet xHalf = ${radius} * (${innerRadius} / 100) * Math.cos((i * eachStepRadian) - eachStepRadian / 2);
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsplet yHalf = ${radius} * (${innerRadius} / 100) * Math.sin((i * eachStepRadian) - eachStepRadian / 2);
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsplet x = ${radius} * Math.cos(i * eachStepRadian);
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsplet y = ${radius} * Math.sin(i * eachStepRadian);
                    <br><br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp// line to half the next step and specified percentage of the radius
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspctx.lineTo(cX + xHalf, cY + yHalf)
                    <br><br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp// line to next stepRadian
                    <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspctx.lineTo(cX + x, cY + y)
                    <br>
                }
                <br><br>
                ctx.strokeStyle = '${strokeColor}';<br>
                ctx.fillStyle = '${fillColor}';<br>
                ctx.lineWidth = ${lineWidth};<br>
                ctx.stroke();<br>
                ctx.fill();<br>
            `
        })


// start the animation cycle
        requestAnimationFrame(rotate)

        function rotate() {
            rotation += rotationSpeed / 100;
            drawStar(radius, steps, rotationSpeed, fillColor, strokeColor);
            requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
        }



        function drawStar() {
            // needs to be reset whenever steps change
            eachStepRadian = (2 * Math.PI) / steps;

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) // clear canvas before drawing new star
            ctx.beginPath();

            // batch drawings together for performance sake
            for (let i = 0; i < steps + 1; i += 1) {
                let xHalf = radius * (innerRadius / 100) * Math.cos(((i * eachStepRadian) - eachStepRadian / 2) + rotation);
                let yHalf = radius * (innerRadius / 100) * Math.sin(((i * eachStepRadian) - eachStepRadian / 2) + rotation);
                let x = radius * Math.cos((i * eachStepRadian) + rotation);
                let y = radius * Math.sin((i * eachStepRadian) + rotation);

                // line to half the next step and specified percentage of the radius
                ctx.lineTo(cX + xHalf, cY + yHalf)

                // line to next stepRadian
                ctx.lineTo(cX + x, cY + y)
            }

            ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
        }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <div id='inputs-container'>
        <div>
            <label for='point-count'>Number of Points</label>
            <input id='point-count' type='number' min="0" max="40" value=5>
        </div>       
        <div>
            <label for='rotation-speed'>Speed of Rotaion</label>
            <input id='rotation-speed' type='number' value=0 min="0" max="10">
        </div>       
        <div>
            <label for='radius'>Radius</label>
            <input id='radius' type='number' value=25 min="0" max="90">
        </div>       
        <div>
            <label for='inner-radius'>Inner Radius %</label>
            <input id='inner-radius' type='number' value=10 min="0" max="100">
        </div>   
        <div>
            <label for='line-width'>Line Width</label>
            <input id='line-width' type='number' value=5 min="0" max="15">
        </div>   
        <div>
            <label for='fill-color'>Fill Color</label>
            <input id='fill-color' type='color' value="#0000ff">
        </div>       
        <div>
            <label for='stroke-color'>Stroke Color</label>
            <input id='stroke-color' type='color'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div >
        <button id='produce-code'>Produce Code (No Rotation)</button>
        <p id='code-to-make'>

        </p>
    </div>
```